# How can I know whether a variable in memory is a pointer or not?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, struct

I'm searching for pointers to structs in the memory of a program, that are 4 bytes away from each other, but the amount can vary. I'm pretty sure that after the structs comes some other variable that's not a pointer.

I figured if I tried to use that next variable as a pointer and apply to it the highest offset the struct I'm looking for can have, GetProcessMemory(I'm doing this in c++ btw) would fail, and I'd know it's not the thing I'm looking for and that the "list" of pointers to structs I'm looking for ends there.

But that seems unreliable since it could happen that that next variable would have a value that pointed to another valid struct and GetProcessMemory would **NOT** fail, so I'm asking if there's a better way.

CheatEngline seems to do it pretty flawlessly, so what am I missing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's no perfectly reliable way, just heuristics, such as the alignment of structure types, and the address ranges used for the heap and stack.

Comment: you can use `typeid(variables).name()` to get the type

Comment: @ Raindrop7  No, you cannot.

Comment: Are you searching inside the memory of another/your own program that was compiled with/without debug information? Do you hook into the program while it is already running, or do you start the program yourself?

Comment: @chtz Another, running.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers translate to addresses.

Addresses are numbers, just like any other number.

You may be able to increase the probability that a number is a pointer, if you know the valid range of addresses.  Although there is no guarantee.

There are no attributes in memory that designate the purpose or type represented by the memory locations.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've been thinking.
This is for a function so I'll most put some parameters (with defaults) like a starting mem addr, the distance between the pointer vars, max amount, and the struct's max offset. With those I can know the exact per say 'length' of the struct, where it starts and and a general idea of where it won't end. The chances of me finding something I'm not looking for are minimal.

The idea is to make a hud for a game that would otherwise not allow it (maybe a hack, since I've never really used too much math in games before - it could be interesting). So maybe I could find some offsets to a variable with the amount of structs I have, then there would be no problems.